# eslint vars-on-top giving warning on const and let declarations and can't be disabled

Tags: javascript, eslint

I want to disable the `vars-on-top` warning because I don't need it as I exclusively use let and const. No matter what value I assign to `vars-on-top` I always get a warning on const and let declarations which says "Var statement is not at scope start". All other eslint configuration options take effect immediately after being changed. Why does vars-on-top not work?

Here's a screenshot of part of my eslint rules and an example of the warning.

[image: eslint settings]

[image: warning example]

Comment: Curious, why do you even have "vars-on-top" defined? Just checked my own settings at https://github.com/geuis/webpack-react-base/blob/master/.eslintrc and I don't have those defined and I don't get your error.

Comment: @Geuis I get the error even if I don't have it defined.

Comment: What IDE and webpack versions are you using?

Comment: @Geuis Not using webpack for this project because there's no client side JS dependencies since it's it's a REST API microservice. Using the latest version of Webstorm.

Comment: Oh sorry Jake, I mean what version of eslint.

Comment: @Geuis eslint version is 5.4.0 if that helps at all.

Comment: @Geuis Ahh that's my bad. I had the default Webstorm linting on AND eslint enabled so it was Webstorm complaining not eslint. I apologize.

Comment: `vars-on-top` isn't a default rule in `eslint:recommended`, so that makes me think you have multiple configurations going on.

Comment: Cool good find on that